# Count down script is not working

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to create a script that will count down to 0 from what ever number I give it. Below is my script and basically nothing happens, no error message, I merely get the standard command line prompt back.

```
#!/bin/bash
#countdown
#counts down to 0 from whatever number you give it
#displaying a number each second

NUM=${1:-0}
if [ $NUM -gt 0 ]
then
   while [ $NUM -gt 0 ]
   do
      if [ -f /usr/bin/banner ]
      then
         /usr/bin/banner "$NUM"
      else
         echo $NUM
      fi
         NUM=$(($NUM-1))
         sleep 2
   done
fi
```

Comment: What is `NUM=${1:-0}`?

Comment: That is a part of the original script my teacher gave me. Is it unnecessary?

Comment: So I made a remark of it: #NUM=${1:-0}

Comment: and got this error message if it helps?  ./count: line 17: [: -gt: unary operator expected

Comment: I tested it. Your script works.

Comment: I suppose you forgot to give it a number as parameter, e.g. `./countdown 30`.

Comment: @HankG: Did you check [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/608807/387382)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "Type an integer number: " && read NUM
if [ $NUM -gt 0 ]
then
   while [ $NUM -ge 0 ]
   do
      if [ -f /usr/bin/banner ]
      then
         /usr/bin/banner "$NUM"
      else
         echo $NUM
      fi
         NUM=$(($NUM-1))
         sleep 2
   done
fi
```

output:

```
:~$ ./countdown.sh 
Type an integer number: 10
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

explanation:
⠀1. line 3 prompts the user to input an integer number and reads it into the variable NUM.
⠀2. Changed the `-gt` in line 6 to `-ge` so that it counts down to zero.
⠀3. The output is displayed in banner format if sysvbanner is installed or else as text if it isn't.

Comment: Sure, that works too. But his original works as well.

Comment: You might want to add *some* explanation, and also why OP's script didn't work.

Comment: Thanks Karel this did the trick!  And thanks A.B. but I don't know why but it would not work for me without the printf line Karel suggested.  Thanks again everyone! :)

Comment: "... why OP's script didn't work ..." :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm The reason why the OP's script didn't work is because of line 6 that says: `NUM=${1:-0}`.  This line has a pattern of the form `${var:-value}`in it which means 'if `$var` is set to any value except the empty string, use it; otherwise, use `value` instead'.  When the command `./countdown.sh` is executed without an integer number after it `$var` is an empty string, so it uses `value` instead which is 0. That means that NUM gets an input of zero, so there is no countdown to output. In order to give NUM some integer input > 0, I replaced that line with code asking to input an integer.

Comment: seems like an excellent addition :)

Answer (score 3):

**Improved and commented code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

num=${1:-undefined}                                   # If $1 (the first argument passed to the script) is set, then num=$1, else num=undefined.
cmd=$(which {banner,echo} | head -1 | xargs basename) # If banner is installed, then cmd=baner, else cmd=echo.

until [[ "$num" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; do                    # Until $num become a valid number (loop will not be executed if $1 is set):
    read -p "Type a number: " num                         # Ask the user for a valid number.
done                                                  # End of the until loop.

for ((num;num>=0;num--)); do                          # Loop using $num as variable; while $num is greater or equal than zero; num=$num-1.
   $cmd $num                                              # Runs $cmd (banner or echo) passing $num as argument.
   sleep 1                                                # Stop the program execution for one second.
done                                                  # End of the for loop.
```

The above code will include zero in the countdown, if do you want to stop when the countdown reaches **1**, then you only need to make a few changes:

1. In the 6th line, change `^[0-9]+$` by `^[1-9]+[0-9]*$` so it looks like this:

   ```
   until [[ "$num" =~ ^[1-9]+[0-9]*$ ]]; do              # Until $num become a valid number (loop will not be executed if $1 is set):
   ```
2. In the 10th line, remove the `=` sign so it looks like this (I've updated also the comment):

   ```
   for ((num;num>0;num--)); do                           # Loop using $num as variable; while $num is strictly greater than zero; num=$num-1.
   ```

---

**Your original program doesn't work because:**

- You not passed a number as argument to the program.
- A example invocation of this command is `./countdown 5` where `5` is the number.
- If do you want to handle this, you can add a `else` to your code (look a the five last lines):

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  #countdown
  #counts down to 0 from whatever number you give it
  #displaying a number each second

  NUM=${1:-0}
  if [ $NUM -gt 0 ]
  then
     while [ $NUM -gt 0 ]
     do
        if [ -f /usr/bin/banner ]
        then
           /usr/bin/banner "$NUM"
        else
           echo $NUM
        fi
           NUM=$(($NUM-1))
           sleep 2
     done
  else
      echo "Error: number not specified."
      echo "Usage: $0 <number>"
      exit 1
  fi
  ```

---

`NUM=${1:-0}` **means:**

> `${PARAMETER:-WORD}`
>
> If the parameter `PARAMETER` is unset (never was defined) or null
>   (empty), this one expands to `WORD`, otherwise it expands to the value
>   of `PARAMETER`, as if it just was `${PARAMETER}`.
>
> ```
> echo "Your home directory is: ${HOME:-/home/$USER}."
> echo "${HOME:-/home/$USER} will be used to store your personal data."
> ```
>
> If `HOME` is unset or empty, everytime you want to print something
>   useful, you need to put that parameter syntax in.

**Source:** http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value

In your case, it means that, if you passed a argument to the script, `NUM` will be equal to that argument, else, `NUM` will be equal to `0`

Comment: Why does the number regex allow negative numbers? I really like the rest of your improved code though.

Comment: @Oli: Sorry, was a mistake, fixed!

Comment: @Oli: Can you fix my answer? English isn't my mother tongue.

Comment: `COMMAND=$(which banner || which echo)` falls back to the echo executable rather than the shell builtin. In bash (this script already uses bash-specific features) you have the echo builtin and may as well use it. Also, if command substitution is used here then in the odd case of whitespace in the full path of banner (`$PATH` entries may contain whitespace, though it's best avoided) it should probably used as `"$COMMAND" $NUM` later in the script. I suggest using [`which banner && COMMAND=banner || COMMAND=echo` or similar](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10826115/), instead.

Comment: @EliahKagan: Ok, I corrected it, however, what about this code `COMMAND=$(eval 'which '{banner,echo}'||' :)` or this one `COMMAND=$(which {banner,echo} | head -n1)` ?       **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

The `NUM=${1:-0}` line means that the variable `NUM` is set to `$1` if a parameter is passed to the script, and to `0` if no parameter is passed at all. That explains why you have no output at all; the threshold is always set to `0` if the script is executed without passing a parameter to it, e.g.:

```
bash <script_name>
```

<sub>*<script_name> = name of your `bash` script;</sub>

or:

```
./<script_name>
```

<sub>*<script_name> = name of your `bash` script;</sub>

So you what you really need to do is to just pass the threshold number to your script upon execution, i.e.:

```
bash <script_name> <threshold_number>
```

<sub>*<script_name> = name of your `bash` script; <number> = thresold number</sub>

or:

```
./<script_name> <threshold_number>
```

<sub>*<script_name> = name of your `bash` script; <number> = thresold number</sub>

Comment: Whoever downvoted this post should be aware that he/she would be *very* welcome to explain what is wrong with it